# Connect to database fail from wordpress in wampserver

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wampserver

I changed the wp-config to the following setting

```
define('DB_Name', 'wp');
define('DB_User', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:3306');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

I got the following error message

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'DB_USER'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:...\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1489

when I changed to 'localhost' to 'myipaddress'

I got the following error message

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host 'xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in C:...\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1489

However, I can login to phpAdmin to create a new database using just the username 'root' without password. I can also go in to mysql without password through MYSQL console

What can I do to solve this problem? How to grant permission?

Thank you,

Comment: Try to use insted localhost 127.0.0.1 for mysql host

Comment: I changed it to 127.0.0.1 I got the same error message. mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'DB_USER'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:....\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1489

Comment: Have you used password in your database because it is showing password not matching and once use just localhost without port 3306.

Answer (score 1):

If in doubt [check the manual](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)

That will tell you that

```
define('DB_Name', 'wp');
define('DB_User', 'root');
```

Should be

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wp');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
```

Comment: good point I omitted reading those lines! Those are specific wordpress constants